# Managing cookies using urllib only

Tags: python-3.x, cookies, urllib

This question has been asked many times but every single accepted answer utilises other librarys. I'm developing within an environment where i cannot use urllib2, http, or requests. My only option is to use urllib or write my own.

I need to send get and post requests to a server locally that requires authentication. I have no problem with the requests and this was all working until the latest security update enforced authentication. Authentication is done via cookies only.

I can send my authentication post and receive a status 200 with successful response. What i'm struggling with is pulling the cookie values out of this response and attaching them to all future post requests using urllib only.

```
import urllib.request, json

url = "serverurl/login"
data = {
    "name" : "username",
    "password" : "password"
}

jsonData = json.dumps(data).encode('utf-8')

req = urllib.request.Request(url, data=jsonData, headers={'content-type': 'application/json'})
response = urllib.request.urlopen(req).read().decode('utf8')
print(response)
```

Answer (score 2):

For others reference, After a few hours of trial and error and cookie research the following got a working solution.

```
import urllib.request, json

url = "serverurl/login"
data = {
    "name" : "username",
    "password" : "password"
}

jsonData = json.dumps(data).encode('utf-8')

req = urllib.request.Request(url, data=jsonData, headers={
    'content-type': 'application/json'
    })

response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
cookies = response.getheader("Set-Cookie")
```

then in future posts you add `"Cookie" : cookies` to the request

```
req = urllib.request.Request(url, data=jsonData, headers={
    "content-type" : "application/json", 
    "Cookie" : cookies
    })
```